# How to create a directory symbol like ~ for HOME?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, bashrc

I've got a directory path for which I want to create a shortcut, like `~` for a users home directory.

I've tried the `ENV` variables, and I could match `$<something>` for a path, but I dont want that `$` letter.

I'm guessing maybe with some kind of `.bashrc` shenanigans?!

Answer (score 1):

I have a handy little function that I use:

```
# A function to help with creating directory aliases and providing
# completion for them.
# Taken from here:
#   http://blog.caioromao.com/2010/10/10/Custom-directory-completion.html
# Tweaked to work with more than just 'cd'
_make_dir_complete() {
    local aliasname=$1
    local prgname="__s_${aliasname}__"

    cd "$3" >/dev/null 2>&1
    local dirname=$(pwd -L)
    local realpath=$(pwd -P)
    cd - >/dev/null 2>&1

    FUNC="function $prgname() {
        local cur len wrkdir;
        local IFS=\$'\\n'
        wrkdir=\"$realpath\"
        cur=\${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]};
        len=\$((\${#wrkdir} + 2));
        COMPREPLY=( \$(compgen -S/ -d \$wrkdir/\$cur| cut -b \$len-) );
    }"
    ALIAS="$aliasname () { $2 \"$dirname/\$*\"; }"

    eval $FUNC
    eval $ALIAS
    complete -o nospace -F $prgname $aliasname
}
```

And then I have some code like this to setup my shortcuts:

```
test -e ~/projects &&
    _make_dir_complete cdp cd ~/projects &&
    _make_dir_complete pdp pushd ~/projects
```

This will set up two bash functions, `cdp` and `pdp`.  `cdp` I use to change directories, so I do something like `cdp foo`, which will translate into `cd ~/projects/foo`.  `pdp` works similarly, but uses `pushd` instead.  The nice part is that it does completion as well, so I can type `cdp f`, then press `TAB`, and it will complete with `cdp foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this set up in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias re='cd /home/terdon/research/'
```

So, if I type `re` at the BASH prompt, I directly `cd` into my `research` directory.

This works fine if you only want to change into the directory in question. Another way would be to set an alias that echoes the directory path:

```
alias foo='echo /path/to/bar'
```

You can then do, for example:

```
$ ls `foo`
```

You will need the inverted commas though. As far as I know there is no way to set up a simple character, with no quotes or `$` to do what you want in BASH. It *is* possible in zsh with "named directories".

Finally, you can find some interesting tips [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1469/22222).